# How to remove/archieve thread in Google Chat room manually or programmatically

Tags: chat, google-workspace, google-chat

I mean [Google Chat](https://chat.google.com/) that come with gSuite

Already find answer at https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3112001?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en but not got any answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way. This is Google's extraordinarily half-baked product meant to take people away from Slack, but then they do stupid things like this. Can't disable threads, can't navigate threads, can't clean up threads. This is supposedly meant to be an enterprise-grade product, but I've seen apps from first-time developers with more functionality than this thing has.

The only way to clear out a thread is to have every user go in and delete all their messages. It's mind-boggling. I don't even know if Google uses this product internally, but I imagine they do not otherwise they would fix that terrible UX.

https://support.google.com/hangouts/thread/61702545?hl=en